# How to store and retrieve messages and related user properties in redis?

Tags: redis, database-schema

I'm running now into some design decision with REDIS and i'm not absolute sure this is the most efficient approach.

Context:

- Store list of users ( ideally hashes, with field "username" )
- Users can update their usernames at any time
- User send messages
- Messages are stored
- Other users can see messages at any time, fields displayed are:

  - timestamp
  - message
  - user username
  - user name
  - user avatar

The first approach, the simplest one :

- Save a JSON string for each message in a Set

The problem is:

- if the user updates his username or avatar

  - JSON string becomes outdated
  - link to profile broken
  - could show old use avatar

Next approach i have in mind:

- Save message as hashes with three fields, user_id, message and timestamp
- Add the message key to "messages" list

Then to display the messages:

- Fetch all messages hashes using SORT messages GET message_*->*
- Get unique user ids in among messages and store in a temporary List

  - Is there a REDIS way of doing this?
- Fetch all users properties using SORT temporary GET user:*->*
- Delete temporary List
- Put messages and users together on my "client code"

Does that make sense?

Comment: You may not want to update the user profile link when the user name changes for various reasons (SEO, bookmarking, etc.,). It would be better for you to use a "user display name" which user can change any time, but keep "user name" unique and you can use that for the profile URL.

Comment: yeah that is a good concern, but i believe users will be notified about it make on their own risk